# How to Check and Confirm Web element is not available in the webpage?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having one action button and this action button will give any of 2 results based on the input Condition. If the Invalid data is provided, then some validation error will be thrown in message table and If valid data is provided, then message table will not exist and it will open another section i.e Message table will be displayed only for the Invalid Data input and it will not be displayed for the Valid Data.

Code:

```
 driver.findElement(By.name("MessageTable")).isDisplayed()
```

If the Valid data is entered, then message table section will not be displayed and hence, getting an error as

```
"no such element: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"name","selector":"MessageTable"}". for the above code.
```

How should I confirm message table is not present in the webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, in Webdriver API, **No** direct method is provided to verify whether element is non existent in a page.

Now in your case, you are sending valid data and you need to verify that validation message does not exist anymore on the page. But for that you are using `findElement()` method which is obviously unable to find that element in page and it throws the expected exception when element doesn't exist.

***Solution:-***

You can write custom method to catch this exception and return boolean value as per your test.

```
public boolean isValidationMsgNotExist() {
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.name("MessageTable"));
        return false;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can modify above method to receive `WebElement` as parameter and verify it exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

I typically do this.

```
List<WebElement> messageTable = driver.findElements(By.name("MessageTable"));
if (messageTable.isEmpty())
{
    // the message table was NOT found
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can try driver.findElements(Locator).size(). If size is 1 then element is found and so on.

Comment: I have tried using the size() Function and it is not working for me and getting an No Such Element Exception. I have handled this exception and achieved my scenario